# subtract date from sql column

Tags: sql, date, dateadd

need ur help again

i have a sql table with column `docid`,`proposedcompletiondate`,`docstatus`

```
doc_id     ProposedCompdate    Docstatus
0001         2011-10-30           A
0002         2011-11-29           C
0003         2011-10-31           C
0004         2011-10-30           A
0005         2011-10-30           C
0006         2011-10-28           C
0007         2011-10-25           A
0008         2011-10-30           C
```

Now i want to write a query to fetch results with `Docstatus` `'A'` whose date when subtracted by 9 days should be current date

for eg if todays Date is '21-10-2011'

the resultset must be

```
doc_id     ProposedCompdate    Docstatus
0001         2011-10-30           A
0004         2011-10-30           A
```

Comment: **WHAT** database and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by **many** database systems - **SQL** is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often **vendor-specific** - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming Microsoft SQL Server, but your where clause would be:

```
where Docstatus = 'A' AND DateDiff(day, GETDATE(), ProposedComplete) = 9
```

The DateDiff function takes a measurement parameter (day, year, etc), a beginning date and and end date and returns an integer.  So the difference between today and ProposedComplete should be 9 days.

Answer (score 1):

Please use DATEADD *SQL SERVER function* where you can add or subtract the date.

for example,

`SELECT DATEADD(day,-9, '2006-06-01') as date_diff;`

According to your question, query may look like,

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,-9, 
   (SELECT ProposedCompdate  FROM Table_name where Docstatus = 'A')) 
AS "-9 Days";
```

Please read more about DATEADD function [here](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqldateadd.php) !!

Comment: By saying *‘SQL function’* you seem to imply a *standard* SQL function, which `DATEADD` is *not* (at the moment). It's a **T-SQL (Transact-SQL)** function.

Comment: Hi Andriy, Before giving the answer, I checked this in SQL server 2008, Its working great !!

Comment: That makes `DATEADD` a **SQL Server** function, not a **SQL** function. Please pay attention to @marc_s's comment to the OP's question about the term *SQL*. The point is, many databases implement their own SQL variations. Not all of those variations have a `DATEADD` function. In fact, date & time handling in SQL is implemented differently across various database systems (and SQL Server is just one of them). So, calling `DATEADD` a SQL function is claiming that it will work in any database system that uses what it calls ‘SQL’.

Comment: Again, SQL Server's particular variation of SQL is called *Transact-SQL*. And Transact-SQL does have this `DATEADD` function you are talking about in your answer. So, saying *‘`DATEADD` is a Transact-SQL function* or *a SQL Server function’* would be both correct and unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

```
select doc_id,ProposedCompdate,Docstatus from tableName where convert(varchar(20),ProposedCompdate,101) = convert(varchar(20),dateadd(d,9,getdate()),101) 
and Docstatus='A'
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine sql server 2008

```
CREATE TABLE #Docs (doc_id varchar(10), ProposedCompdate date,Docstatus  nvarchar(50))

INSERT INTO #Docs(doc_id, ProposedCompdate, Docstatus) VALUES(0001,'2011-10-30','A')
INSERT INTO #Docs(doc_id, ProposedCompdate, Docstatus) VALUES(0002,'2011-11-29','C')
INSERT INTO #Docs(doc_id, ProposedCompdate, Docstatus) VALUES(0003,'2011-10-31','C')
INSERT INTO #Docs(doc_id, ProposedCompdate, Docstatus) VALUES(0004,'2011-10-30','A')
INSERT INTO #Docs(doc_id, ProposedCompdate, Docstatus) VALUES(0005,'2011-10-30','C')
INSERT INTO #Docs(doc_id, ProposedCompdate, Docstatus) VALUES(0006,'2011-10-28','C')
INSERT INTO #Docs(doc_id, ProposedCompdate, Docstatus) VALUES(0007,'2011-10-25','A')
INSERT INTO #Docs(doc_id, ProposedCompdate, Docstatus) VALUES(0008,'2011-10-30','C')

SELECT * FROM #Docs WHERE CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(D, 9, GETDATE())) = ProposedCompdate AND Docstatus = 'A'

DROP TABLE #Docs
```